# Codeigniter Error - Duplicate entry '2' for key 'PRIMARY' UPDATE `tickets` SET `id` = '2', `status` = 1

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm building a support system with Codeigniter 3.
When the ticket status is 0, there is no problem, but when I want to set the current status to 1, I get an error.
My database "TNYINT" Length 1 default value 0

if i send it as 0 it's ok but when admin posts this i have to make it 1.

```
    /*** Reply Ticket Post */
    public function admin_reply_ticket_post()
    {

        /// Admin Authority Checkup Getting Started
        adminCheck();
        // Admin Authority Check End
        
        $data = array(
            'ticket_id' => $this->input->post('ticket_id'),
            'admin_id' => $this->session->userdata('adminid'),
            'first_name' => $this->session->userdata('first_name'),
            'last_name' => $this->session->userdata('last_name'),
            'message' => $this->input->post('message')
        );

        $this->db->insert('tickets_sub', $data);

        // Make Ticket Status "in the transaction"
        $data = array(
            'id' => $this->input->post('ticket_id'),
            'status' => 1 ,
        );
        $this->db->update('tickets', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you're giving **all** the records in the `tickets` table a new `id` and `status`, that's why you're getting the "Duplicate" error. You need to add a `WHERE` clause to specify which record to update:

```
    // Make Ticket Status "in the transaction"
    $data = array(
        'status' => 1 ,
    );
    $this->db->where('id' => $this->input->post('ticket_id'));
    $this->db->update('tickets', $data);
```

Or even shorter:

```
    // Make Ticket Status "in the transaction"
    $data = array(
        'status' => 1 ,
    );
    $this->db->update('tickets', $data, array('id' => $this->input->post('ticket_id')));
```

See: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#updating-data

Comment: Yes, I was very sleep deprived and I couldn't see if I was wrong, so I solved it in the following way.
Thanks for the help.
  
// Make Ticket Status "in the transaction"
  $this->db->set('status', 1);
  $this->db->where('id', $this->input->post('ticket_id'));
  $trans = $this->db->update('tickets');

Comment: Also, I'm wondering if you know anything about it.

I'm using "tinymce" and I don't want to use it with textarea tag, so I make textareaweb, but the system doesn't read it while saving the name part to the database.
There is no problem opening the editor.